# Error on Intent Activity in android studio. (Automatically change background)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-intent, intentfilter

> Hello and good luck to everyone.
>
> I am using Intent Activity in my project. And are having bugs with it.
>   As follows: I have a list of the order of Activity:
>
> A (Main) -> B (Login or SignUp) -> C (Menu) -> D (ListFoodOfMenu) -> E
>   (DetailsFood)
>
> From A-B-C-D or in many different order does not occur
>   error.
>
> But, since D-E has an error, the backgroud that I set for the xml
>   layout disappears throughout the application, replacing it with the
>   system color.

Who has a solution to help me and what to do to handle this error. Thank you.

This is a UI when there are no errors and then the UI is faulty:

[UI is not faulty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AURTW.png)

[UI is faulty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGCHr.png)

This is my code Intent:

A-B:

```
btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent moveToSignUp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(moveToSignUp);
                finishActivity(1);
            }
        });

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent moveToSignIn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInActivity.class);
                startActivity(moveToSignIn);
                finishActivity(1);
            }
        });
```

B-C:

```
Intent moveToHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                                    Common.currentUser = user;
                                    startActivity(moveToHome);
```

C-D:

```
//Get CategoryID and send to new Activity:
                        Intent moveToFoodList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FoodListActivity.class);
                        //Because CategoryID is Key, so we just get key of this item:
                        moveToFoodList.putExtra("CategoryID", adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(moveToFoodList);
```

D-E:

```
//Start Activity FoodDetails
                        Intent moveToFoodDetails = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FoodDetailsActivity.class);
                        moveToFoodDetails.putExtra("FoodId", searchAdapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        // Send FoodId to FoodDetailsActivity
                        moveToFoodDetails.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                        startActivity(moveToFoodDetails);
```

E-D (At this point the error has occurred):

```
btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new Database(getApplicationContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                        "", //Id tự tăng
                        Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                        FoodId,
                        currentFood.getName(),
                        numberButton.getNumber(),
                        currentFood.getPrice(),
                        currentFood.getDiscount()
                ));
               finish();
        Toast.makeText(FoodDetailsActivity.this, "Added To Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

> I have struggled with this error for months and still can not figure
>   out how to fix it. We look forward to much help from Pro. Sincerely
>   thank.

Comment: I created demo with your code & working fine..! Can you give more detail

Comment: I do not know what information to provide. Hope you can take the time to download and use to see the error
This is link my project: https://github.com/lexuandu98/TheFoodHouse_Client

Comment: I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: Can you give me some dummy login credentials.!

Comment: phone:01655933593
pass: 111398

Comment: I found it on github and it does not work

Comment: I tried deleting it but still nothing changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are having library `'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'` & that library also has background resource named `background.xml` which is being **override with your** `background.jpg`, when you reach `FoodDetailsActivity` screen.

**Solution** : *Rename* your `background.jpg` *to* `background_1.jpg`.

Comment: OK. Thank you PRO. Everything was settled and I was very pleased.

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use getApplicationContext() at all places.

Use Activity's object like SignUpActivity.this or SignInActivity.this.

Comment: OK. Let me try and tell you about the results

Comment: I tried to change the results are still not good.
Looking forward to providing you more direction for me

Comment: I do not know what information to provide. Hope you can take the time to download and use to see the error This is link my project: github.com/lexuandu98/TheFoodHouse_Client

you can login with:
phone: 01655933597
pass:111398

Comment: OK. 
Thank you PRO for helping me. I have found the correct answer from @buzzingsilently